# I can't install JMSSerializerBundle in symfony3.1 project

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, symfony-3.1

I'm trying to install JMSSerializerBundle in symfony3.1 project but I get this error

command:

```
php ../composer.phar require jms/serializer-bundle -vvv
```

> Using version ^2.0 for jms/serializer-bundle
>     [UnexpectedValueException]
>     Could not parse version constraint update: Invalid version string "update"
>
> Exception trace:
>    () at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/composer.phar/vendor/composer/semver/src/VersionParser.php:485
>    Composer\Semver\VersionParser->parseConstraint() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/composer.phar/vendor/composer/semver/src/VersionParser.php:249
>    Composer\Semver\VersionParser->parseConstraints() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionParser.php:27
>    Composer\Package\Version\VersionParser->parseConstraints() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php:126
>    Composer\Command\RequireCommand->execute() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:267
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:846
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:191
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:227
>    Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:122

Comment: Did you see my answer @hous?

Comment: yes I did , and the solution is to add this "jms/serializer-bundle": "^2.0" in the composer.json and do update

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you see this issue, but can you try these commands:

```
php ../composer.phar self-update
php ../composer.phar update
php ../composer.phar require jms/serializer-bundle
```

In that order. I'm thinking maybe your composer version is out of date, but not certain if that will resolve the issue. Let me know if it does.

---

The correct command for you based on comments would then be:

```
php ../composer.phar require jms/serializer-bundle "^2.0"
```

See if that works.